# Is there setDelayThreshold() command for PubSubIO write in Apache Beam?

Tags: streaming, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

Is there an option of not only setting the maxBatchSize() for the bulk PubSubIO write request in Apache Beam, but to also give a time limit for it? In the documentation it is written

> For example, if given 1000 the write sink will wait until 1000 messages have been
> received, or the pipeline has finished, whichever is first.

Hence, if neither the sink is full nor pipeline has finished, it might mean that the messages will be stored there forever? What are the possible workarounds for this situation?

I expect to be able to set a timeout for sending bulk messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a Streaming pipeline? If so, by default, it uses [PubsubUnboundedSink](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/pubsub/PubsubUnboundedSink.java#L94-L95) and has a default maximum latency of 2 seconds. In this case, 2 seconds is basically the "time limit" that you are describing.

If it is a batch, work is processed in bundles (see [link](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runtime/model/#data-partitioning-and-inter-stage-execution)) and the writes happen upon bundle finalization.

So what you are describing of messages being stored forever should not be observed. Please update with more information if you are noticing such behavior.

Comment: In my case it is a streaming pipeline and I was also able to figure out today by checking the source code that there is a standard 2 sec limit. However, I assume that there is no way of controlling it?

Comment: Seems like PubsubIO doesn't offer any way to pass through a maximum latency to the PubsubUnboundedSink. I'd file an issue at https://github.com/apache/beam/issues if this is highly desired.

Comment: I think it would be comfortable to have, so that the Apache Beam transform mirrors as much as possible the configuration options available in the standard PubSub client and there is already some source code present in regards to this case, it just needs to become more accessible and manageable by the developers I guess. However, I am still pretty new to Apache Beam and I cannot evaluate precisely the impact of my request. Thank you for the answer, Bruno!